# Proving for $n \ge 25$, $p_n > 3.75n$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

The elements of the [reduced residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system) modulo $30$ are $\{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29\}$

If we order them as $e_1, e_2, e_3, \dots$ so that $e_1 = 1, e_2 = 7, \dots$, it follows that $3.75(i-1) < e_i < 3.75i$.

We can generalize this.

If $\gcd(x,30)=1,$ then $x = 30a + b$ where $b \in \{1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29\}$.

If we order $\{1,7, 11, \dots, 29, 31, \dots, 59, \dots, 30a-1, \dots, x, \dots, 30a+31, \dots, 30a+59 \}$ as $e_1, e_2, e_3, \dots$ there exists $j$ with $e_j = x$ and $3.75(j-1) < x < 3.75j$.  (This is true for $x < 30$.  Assume it is true for $x < 30c$ where $c \ge 1$.  It is clearly also true for each $e_j=x$ where $x < 30(c+1)$).

For $4 \le i \le 15$, $p_i = e_{i-2} > (i-3)*3.75$.

For $16 \le i \le 21$, $p_i = e_{i-1} > (i-2)*3.75$

For $22 \le i \le 24$, $p_i = e_i > (i-1)*3.75$

For $i \ge 25$, $p_i \ge e_{i+1} > 3.75i$

Is this reasoning valid?  If so, what would be a more concise way of making the same argument?

Comment: An overkill approach : $ p_n \sim n \log n$ from prime numbers theorem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, $p_n > n\log{n}$ (Rosser's Theorem) for sufficiently large $n$. And since $\log{n}$ is unbounded (in particular, is not bounded by 3.75), such a result is to be expected.

To limit the number of particular cases that must be checked manually, we can invoke a [refinement of Rosser's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) according to which
$$p_n > n(\log{n} + \log{\log{n}} - 1),\; \forall n \ge 6.$$

It turns out that the function $f: x \mapsto \log{x} + \log{\log{x}} - 1$ is increasing for $x > 1$, and that $f(34) >  3.7866268 > 3.75$. Thus we obtain that
$$ p_n > 3.75n,\; \forall n \ge 34.$$

Now check the remaining cases $p_{25}, p_{26},\ldots, p_{33}$ with a small script :)

Comment: Thanks very much!  I was not familiar with Rosser's Theorem.  I appreciate the reference and the analysis.